# Can't find out why am I getting back undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Below code is to get the google analytics dataLayer object and display it. But When I run the code as a bookmarklet I always get 11 or the exact number of items as undefineds.

```
var newWindow = open('',width=500,height=500);

newWindow.document.write("<html><head></head><body><input value='REFRESH!' type='button' id='button'><br></body></html>");

var button = newWindow.document.getElementById('button');

var dataArray = [];

button.onclick = function() {
    dataArray = (dataLayer);
    for(var key in dataArray){
        var obj = dataArray[key];
        for(var i in obj){
            newWindow.document.writeln(dataArray[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

With a simple for loop at button click;

```
    for (var i = 0; i < dataLayer.length; i++) {
    dataArray[i] = (dataLayer[i]);
    console.log(dataArray[i]);
}
```

I'am able to display all the data at the parent console.

Comment: For starters, what is dataLayer?

Comment: @Nit, it's part of Google Analytics, as the OP mentions.

Comment: `dataArray = (dataLayer)` actually seems not an array, you should use `dataArray = [dataLayer]`, if `dataLayer` is already an array you should use it directily

Comment: @Sanção you are right, the original code is not like that. IDK what happened when I've copied over here. But thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are iterating over all elements in the elements of `dataArray`. But then you print the index of `dataArray`. Try

```
 dataArray[key][i]
```

or

```
 obj[i]
```

Comment: YES!!! Worked like a charm. I guess I'm still sleeping.. Need some coffee here :)